# No funciona el Textvariable= de python/tkinter o el tk.intvar()

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Creé un ventana con `tkinter` que al oprimir un botón abre una subventana que tiene una casillas para agregar unos datos, todo bien hasta ahí.
Este es el código de la ventana principal:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from Fitareas import Agregar
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class VentanaPrincipal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame_actual = None

        self.title("Gestor de Tareas")

        ancho_ventana = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        alto_ventana = self.winfo_screenheight()
        ventana_ancho = int(ancho_ventana * 0.6)
        ventana_alto = int(alto_ventana * 0.71)
        self.geometry(f"{ventana_ancho}x{ventana_alto}")

        self.resizable(False, False)

        barra_lateral = tk.Frame(self, width=100, bg="#0E3872")

        self.icono1 = self.cargar_imagen(
            "Gestor-de-tareas/Interfaz/Imagenes/crecuencia.png", (30, 30))
        self.icono2 = self.cargar_imagen(
            "Gestor-de-tareas/Interfaz/Imagenes/cechas.png", (30, 30))
        self.icono3 = self.cargar_imagen(
            "Gestor-de-tareas/Interfaz/Imagenes/configuraciones.png", (30, 30))

        boton1 = self.crear_boton(
            barra_lateral, self.icono1, lambda: self.mostrar_interfaz(Itareas))
        boton2 = self.crear_boton(
            barra_lateral, self.icono2, lambda: self.mostrar_interfaz(Ihistorial))
        boton3 = self.crear_boton(
            barra_lateral, self.icono3, lambda: self.mostrar_interfaz(Isettings))

        boton1.pack(side="top", pady=10, padx=7)
        boton2.pack(side="top", pady=10, padx=7)
        boton3.pack(side="bottom", pady=10, padx=7)
        barra_lateral.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self.mostrar_interfaz(Itareas)

    def cargar_imagen(self, ruta, tamaño):
        imagen = Image.open(ruta)
        imagen = imagen.resize(tamaño)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)

    def crear_boton(self, master, imagen, comando):
        boton = tk.Button(master, image=imagen, bd=0, relief="flat",
                          highlightthickness=0, bg="#0E3872", command=comando)
        boton.config(activebackground=boton.cget('background'),
                     activeforeground=boton.cget('foreground'))
        return boton

    def mostrar_interfaz(self, interfaz):
        if self.frame_actual is not None:
            self.frame_actual.destroy()

        if self.frame_actual == interfaz:
            return

        self.frame_actual = interfaz(self)
        self.frame_actual.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


class Itareas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(bg="#081F3F")

        self.boton_agregar = tk.Button(self, text="Agregar", command=Agregar)
        self.boton_editar = tk.Button(self, text="Editar")
        self.boton_eliminar = tk.Button(self, text="Eliminar")

        self.boton_agregar.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)
        self.boton_editar.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.boton_eliminar.grid(row=1, column=2)

        c_largo = int(self.winfo_vrootwidth() * 0.37)
        c_ancho = int(self.winfo_vrootheight() * 0.31)

        self.crear_marco_tareas("En espera", "#081F3F", c_ancho, c_largo).grid(
            padx=15, pady=10, column=0, row=2)
        self.crear_marco_tareas("En proceso", "yellow", c_ancho, c_largo).grid(
            padx=15, pady=10, column=1, row=2)
        self.crear_marco_tareas("Finalizado", "blue", c_ancho, c_largo).grid(
            padx=15, pady=10, column=2, row=2)

    def crear_marco_tareas(self, titulo, color_fondo, ancho, alto):
        marco = tk.Frame(self, width=ancho, height=alto,
                         bg=color_fondo, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
        marco.pack_propagate(False)
        titulo_label = tk.Label(
            marco, text=titulo, font=("Arial", 15), bg=color_fondo)
        titulo_label.pack(side="top", fill=tk.X)
        lista_tareas = tk.Listbox(marco, bg="#081F3F")
        lista_tareas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        return marco


class Ihistorial(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        c_largo = int(self.winfo_vrootwidth() * 0.37)
        c_ancho = int(self.winfo_vrootheight() * 1)
        marco_historial = self.crear_marco_historial(c_ancho, c_largo)
        marco_historial.grid(padx=15, pady=10, column=1, row=2)

    def crear_marco_historial(self, ancho, alto):
        marco = tk.Frame(self, width=ancho, height=alto,
                         bg="red", relief="solid")
        marco.pack_propagate(False)
        return marco


class Isettings(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)


root = VentanaPrincipal()
root.mainloop()
```

Creo una casilla con un numero fijo de 1 al 12 que el usuario puede incrementar o decrementar con dos botones.
Ésta aparece correctamente cuando lo abro con la ventana principal.
Solo funciona cuando ejecuto la función desde el archivo py de la subventana. No sé qué está mal o qué ocurre.
Este es el código de la subventana:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import os


class Agregar(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        valor_inicial = 1

        self.title("Agregar tarea")
        self.configure(bg="#081F3F")

        ruta_database = os.path.join(
            "Gestor-de-tareas", "base_de_datos.db")

        conexion = sqlite3.connect(ruta_database)
        cursor = conexion.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Datos")

        til = tk.Label(self, text="Nombre de la tarea", font=(
            "calibri", 12), bg="#081F3F", fg="white")
        til.grid(padx=2, pady=3, row=0, column=0)
        entrada = tk.Entry(self, font=("Arial", 14))
        entrada.grid(pady=5, padx=10, row=1, column=0)

        til1 = tk.Label(self, text="Descripción", font=(
            "calibri", 12), bg="#081F3F", fg="white")
        til1.grid(padx=2, pady=3, row=2, column=0)
        entrada1 = tk.Entry(self, font=("Arial", 14))
        entrada1.grid(pady=5, padx=10, row=3, column=0)

        til1 = tk.Label(self, text="Prioridad", font=(
            "calibri", 12), bg="#081F3F", fg="white")
        til1.grid(padx=2, pady=3, row=0, column=1)

        opciones = ["Selecione...", "Prioridad alta",
                    "Prioridad media", "Prioridad baja"]
        entrada3 = ttk.Combobox(self, values=opciones, state="readonly")
        entrada3.current(0)
        entrada3.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.valor = tk.StringVar()
        self.valor.set(str(valor_inicial))

        self.entry = tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.valor, width=5, justify='center')
        self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.btn_arriba = tk.Button(
            self, text='▲', command=lambda: incrementar(self))
        self.btn_arriba.grid()

        self.btn_abajo = tk.Button(
            self, text='▼', command=lambda: decrementar(self))
        self.btn_abajo.grid()

        def incrementar(self):
            nuevo_valor = (int(self.valor.get()) % 12) + 1
            self.valor.set(str(nuevo_valor))

        def decrementar(self):
            nuevo_valor = (int(self.valor.get()) - 2) % 12 + 1
            self.valor.set(str(nuevo_valor))

        boton_guardar = tk.Button(
            self, text="Guardar", command=lambda: Guardar(self, entradas=entrada))
        boton_guardar.grid(row=5, column=3)

        boton_guardar = tk.Button(
            self, text="Cancelar", command=lambda: cancelar(self))
        boton_guardar.grid(row=5, column=4)

        def Guardar(self, entradas):

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Datos (Nombre , Descripcion, Prioridad) VALUES(?,?,?)",
                           (entrada.get(), entrada1.get(), entrada3.get()))

            conexion.commit()
            return self.destroy()

        def cancelar(self):
            self.destroy()


root = Agregar()

root.mainloop()
```

Creo que el error puede estar en `textvariable=self.valor`. O quizás es que `valor = tk.intvar()` no se transfiere bien a la ventana principal.

Comment: No suele ser conveniente usar la clase Tk para ventanas secundarias. Las clases Tk solo deben instanciarse una vez. De lo contrario, Tkinter se comporta fuera de lo habitual (trayendo prpblemas como el del StringVar). Lo mejor es usar la clase Toplevel, que además se cierra cuando su ventana padre es cerrada, un comportamiento habitualmente util.